# Error with print function: 'TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable'

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm getting this error message whenever I try to use the `print` function:
[image: TypeError]

It shows the same error, regardless of what object I'm trying to print (array, syntax, number...).
Has this ever happened to anyone and if so, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Something naughty in this namespace did a `print = ...` assignment.  Use `del print`.

Comment: You can check this with `type(print)`. It should say `builtin_function_or_method`. If you've overwritten `print`, it will instead say something else